# Spring Cloud Stream: consumer for different message types

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

With a StreamBridge I send messages with two different types of objects to a single Kafka topic.
Is there a way to define a functional consumer with Spring Cloud Stream capable of consuming both types of messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [event routing feature](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_event_routing), you can have multiple consumers and then route to the right consumer using the routing function. See this [sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/main/routing-samples/message-routing-callback) for something more advanced. However, I realize that this is not your use case, but wanted to mention it just in case. On the consumer side, having multiple types accepted is hard if using domain objects. For example, if your incoming POJO is Foo (`Consumer<Foo>`), it will fail on deserialization if you are sending `Bar` to it. If you are willing to accept `Consumer<byte[]`, then you can just use a `ByteArrayDeserializer` and then turn on native decoding in the app, so that no conversion is attempted. Once you receive your `byte[]`, then you can maybe trying to use an `ObjectMappter` or similar mechanism to build your actual object with the proper type.

Comment: I have a similar use-case where I don't know if it is better to have a separate consumer for each message type or to have one consumer that accepts an object and later on do the downcasting/deserialization in the code. What is the best practice currently?